# BUFFER TIMEOUT exoplayer android..stuck on buffering

Tags: android, streaming, buffer, exoplayer

I'm using Exoplayer for mp3 streaming (Via http) 
sometimes the player stuck at buffering and the weird thing is this log 
BUFFER TIMEOUT ...
I had tried to increase buffer size and retry counts but nothing

init :

```
     private static final int BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE = 64 * 1024;
        private static final int RENDERER_COUNT = 1;//since you want to render simple audio
        private static final int minBufferMs = 2500;
        private static final int minRebufferMs = 5000;
        private static final int BUFFER_SEGMENT_COUNT = 256;
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
       this.exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Factory.newInstance(RENDERER_COUNT, minBufferMs, minRebufferMs);
                this.exoPlayer.addListener(this);
```

play function :

```
            Allocator allocator = new DefaultAllocator(BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE);

            DataSource dataSource = new DefaultHttpDataSource(userAgent, null, null);
            sampleSource = new ExtractorSampleSource(uri,
                    dataSource
                    , allocator,
                    BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE,
                    BUFFER_SEGMENT_COUNT * BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE);
        }
        MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer audioRenderer = new MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer(sampleSource);
   exoPlayer.prepare(audioRenderer);
        exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Have you managed to solve it?

Comment: So lately but update to exoplayer to 2.2 and most of the bugs are fixed

Comment: Nevertheless; thank you very much! In my case it seemed that the stream itself was corrupt.